# Swift: using plist - error: value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I am very beginner in Swift and I got stuck in this question:

Given a resource named "CrazyInformation.plist" located in the main application directory, first retrieve the path to this resource and assign the string to a constant named plistPath.
Once you have the plistPath, create an instance of NSDictionary containing the contents of the plist.

I am trying this:

```
import Foundation

// Add your code below
var plistPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("CrazyInformation ",ofType: "plist") 
var information = NSArray(contentsOfFile: plistPath)
```

However, I got this error:

> swift_lint.swift:7:43: error: value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
>   var information = NSArray(contentsOfFile: plistPath)

How could I unwrapped this?

Comment: Did you even *try* what the compiler error message suggests? – Or simply click on the red dot and select "Fix-it" ? – Or lookup one of the many questions about exactly the same error message?

Answer (score 2):

The return type of `pathForResource` is `String?` i.e. if there is no file of this name in the bundle, it might return a nil.

A good way of writing this code would be

```
if let plistPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("CrazyInformation", ofType: "plist") {
    var information = NSArray(contentsOfFile: plistPath)
}
```

This will ensure that the code inside the if condition is only executed if `pathForResource` returns a not-nil value

Answer (score 1):

```
var plistPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("CrazyInformation ",ofType: "plist")!
```

See more of optionals [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because your using NSArray but the type of CrazzyInformation is a dictionary? I am a beginner as well,  but I think that might be it. Try using NSDictionary.